# Can Firestore Scale

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Can the new `Firestore` service scale?
I know it's in beta. I'm looking for some live examples of `Firestore` Scaling.

In terms of:

- Number of database transactions.
- Size of database.

Also - Does firebase have some auto scaling policy.
Can `Firebase` itself scales in terms of:

- Number of users (using the OAuth)

Does anyone have some Firebase scaling example and could share.

Answer (score 11):

*firebaser here*

The first line on  the [main documentation page for Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/):

> Use our flexible, **scalable** NoSQL cloud database to store and sync data for client- and server-side development.

A bit lower in [key capabilities](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/#key_capabilities):

> **Designed to scale**
>
> Cloud Firestore brings you the best of Google Cloud Platform's powerful infrastructure: automatic multi-region data replication, strong consistency guarantees, atomic batch operations, and real transaction support. We've designed Cloud Firestore to handle the toughest database workloads from the world's biggest apps.

That tells you that the folks that created Cloud Firestore thinks that scalability is one of its key features. Give that these are the same folks that worked on many of Google Cloud Platform's features, I tend to believe them on that front. :-)

There were also some earlier questions that may be relevant:

- [What's the difference between Cloud Firestore and the Firebase Realtime Database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46549766/whats-the-difference-between-cloud-firestore-and-the-firebase-realtime-database)

> **Designed to Scale** -- Cloud Firestore will be able to scale better than the Realtime Database. It's important to note that your queries scale to the size of your result set, not your data set. So searching will remain fast no matter how large your data set might become.

- [Queries scale with the size of your result set, not the size of your data set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46603205/queries-scale-with-the-size-of-your-result-set-not-the-size-of-your-data-set/46608084#46608084)

Just keep in mind that Cloud Firestore is still in beta and will be slower (but scale better) than Firebase's realtime database:

- [Firestore slow performance issue on getting data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46717898/firestore-slow-performance-issue-on-getting-data/46750456#46750456)

Comment: Thanks for your reply @frank. Yes I believe that Google engineers have better chances at scaling then my new scaling policies, database, etc. I needed to confirm that again, since I will I start with MVP then to a larger system that needs be self host at some point. I'm trying to guess in which points in time will it happen.
From your experience. What would be that thing that I will need to scale first, working with firebase. I believe perhaps the Cloud functions. From the documentation: "It may take more than 5 seconds for a function to be triggered after a change to Cloud Firestore data."

Comment: My application has 200,000 active users per month. Will firestore withstand such a load?

Comment: The number of active users is not a limiting factor for Firestore, but during the beta period there is a limit of 100K **concurrent** users (see [the documentation on limits and quota](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas)). With 200K MAU you typically will have much fewer than 100K concurrents, but that of course depends on your app/use-case.

Comment: What happens if I exceed the limit of Document reads 1,000,000,000?

Comment: It might scale on terms of read operations, but doesn't sound like it does on writes. The documentation says, that it can only handle 1 write operation on document per second. https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/counters