# Can i overpass firebase cloud free limit with 200 users

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Is it possible that with 100 quotes written i consumed 80k Reed quotes, on firebase storage?! And all it with 200 user on my application.

I have passed my project with payment because i overpass the limit 50k Reed per day

Comment: If you have concerns about the billing for your Firebase project, you should reach out to [Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support) directly.  Stack Overflow is for questions about programming.

Answer (score 0):

if you are concern with the scalability fo firestore then you should know firebase is mainly designed to target this problem as firebase has horizontal scalability , also read [can-firestore-scale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46876532/can-firestore-scale) .

also i think you also concern about the limit read , write limit then read [release-notes#October_17_2022](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/release-notes#October_17_2022)

> The following database limits no longer apply:
>
> 1.Maximum writes per second per database: 10,000
>
> 2.Maximum concurrent connections for mobile/web clients per database: 1,000,000

even there are some of the features that has limit (go through [quotas](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas)) but most of them can be increased ,you just need to contact with the [firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support%5D) for that

only thing is that you will pay as you go that means you have to pay to only the extra services  you used that are not cover or exceeded from your free tire according to the [pricing](https://firebase.google.com/pricing).

will be helpful to read [Scale with Multiple Databases](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/sharding)