# React Native and Firestore

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, mobile-application

I am beginner on firebase and need some help with project decision. I am building a react native app for someone and for the database I was thinking of using firebase, but when I was going through the docs I realized that firestore offers Backend Service, does this mean I don't have to use any framework for the backend. I was originally planning to use Django but if firestore provides backend service, it will provide lot more ease to the project. Can anyone give me an explanation on this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed directly connect your ReactJS application to Cloud Firestore, bypassing the need for your own server. To secure the application you'd use Firebase's [server-side security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/overview), which allow you to control who can read and write what data. This is of course extra important, since you're opening up the database for direct access from the client applications, and the rest of the internet.

To access Firebase from React Native, many developers use the [`react-native-firebase` library](https://rnfirebase.io/), which wraps more Firebase services than the JavaScript SDK does.

Comment: Thank your for the response Frank. Just to be clarified, I am not suppose to write any back-end code right. I am just supposed to integrate firestore on my react native. Also while I have chance to ask, what is the difference between firebase and firestore?

Comment: Firebase is a platform with 18 products, two if which are databases. One database is the Realtime Database, which was also Firebase's original product. The other database is Cloud Firestore, which was created to solve some of the Realtime Database's scalability limits (trading of for its own limits of course). If you'd like to learn more about the difference, and which one to use for what, have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46549766/whats-the-difference-between-cloud-firestore-and-the-firebase-realtime-database