# what is the advantage of firestore compared to firebase rtdb regarding to the price

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

recently Im learning firebase, for instance to create a chat app, it seems that firestore will be much expensive than firebase rtdb, except this normally the CRUD has small size of data, so I feel rtdb will be always more cost-effective than firestore, is that correct? thanks for any clues!

Comment: I recommend starting with https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rtdb-vs-firestore and Todd's excellent answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46549766/whats-the-difference-between-cloud-firestore-and-the-firebase-realtime-database

Comment: hi @Frank, thanks for the reply and the help to the people like who is learning firebase:)