# This code is for Firestore but how I'll write this code for realtime database firebase in flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

Here I am trying to retrive data from realtime database in flutter

```
Future<UserModel> getUserDrtails(String email) async{
    final snapshot = await _db.collection("User").where("Email", isEqualTo: email).get();
    final userData = snapshot.docs.map((e)=>UserModel.fromSnapshot(e)).single;
    return userData;

  }
```

Here data is retrived from firestore database but I am using realtime database so what I have to change to retrive data from realtime database.
While using realtime database this code gives error at "collection"

Answer (score 0):

While Firestore and the Realtime Database are both part of Firebase, they are completely separate and each have their own API.

To get started with the Firebase Realtime Database, have a look [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/flutter/read-and-write). You'll indeed find that Realtime Database doesn't have a concept of collections nor of documents, but instead has a data model that is one bug tree of JSON data. So you'll want to modify your data model to fit that.

For more on this and other changes, also see [What's the difference between Cloud Firestore and the Firebase Realtime Database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46549766/whats-the-difference-between-cloud-firestore-and-the-firebase-realtime-database)

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this for `realtime database:`

```
final ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref();
final snapshot = await ref.child('users/$userId').get();
if (snapshot.exists) {
    print(snapshot.value);
} else {
    print('No data available.');
}
```

Refer: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/database/read-and-write

Comment: While this is valid code, it doesn't provide a solution to the question - the OP is *querying* the Firestore database for any documents that have a given email address in the Email field. This code doesn't do that - it reads a specific node from the Realtime Database. Still good code but it would be a better answer if it performed the same query.